# How to publish & consume Blob Stream message using Message Queue?

Tags: stream, jms, blob, activemq-classic, message-queue

I'm trying to produce and consume blob(pdf) and stream(log ) file from message queue using java(jms).After googling ,i found that ActiveMQ support Blob message.I tried to implement using ActiveMQ. But there is no complete solution or example over the internet.

Could you please help me by giving **sample code (with proper broker url)** or how to do this? Also is there any other MQ that support Stream & Blob messages?

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you want to do, what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Actually my requirement is to have a wrapper restfull service over the mQ,so that Blob(pdf,excel,rtf )file and stream (log,text)  can be published and consumed.I tried the exaple from here but it didnot work  http://activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html

Comment: @TimBish Im not sure what to put in the upload url value given below( i even tired with localhost) tcp://localhost:61616?jms.blobTransferPolicy.uploadUrl=http://foo.com  but nothing is working, i keep getting an exception: javax.jms.JMSException :PUT was not successful: 404 Not Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default url should be like this:

```
tcp://localhost:61616?jms.blobTransferPolicy.defaultUploadUrl=http://localhost:8161/fileserver/
```

If you need a complete code solution,please go through this link below:

http://kuntalganguly.blogspot.in/2014/07/publish-consume-blob-and-stream-message.html

Comment: Thanks its working!!but can you just tell me if i use a different default url,will it work? say like http://localhost:8080/fileupload/